# 3 different distinct values from the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I will have an sql table named VISIT table.

I have 3 columns

> WORKSTATION, CATEGORY, BUTTON
>
> 1          ,1        , 1
>
> 1          ,2        , 3
>
> 1          ,1        , 2
>
> 2          ,1        , 1
>
> 2          ,3        , 1
>
> 2          ,1        , 2

How can I query that table to get the distinct values for each column in one query statement?

the result should be sth like..

> WORKSTATION, CATEGORY, BUTTON
>
> 1          ,1        , 1
>
> 2          ,2        , 2
>
> - ,3        , 3

I can do that with 3 different queries. I just wonder can this be done in one query as that will make the program run faster.

Comment: Why should 3 appear in WOSKSTATION ?

Comment: Have you measured the current performance? Is this definitely something you actually need to improve?

Comment: definitely, as it will take some time to calculate in the latter part.

Comment: The result I want is.. distinct value for each column, not relating to another column..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to do this with column-per-column is IMO a mistake; just do it in two columns and pick out the column at the caller:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'WS' AS [Col], WORKSTATION AS [Value] FROM VISIT
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'CA' AS [Col], CATEGORY AS [Value]  FROM VISIT
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'BU' AS [Col], BUTTON AS [Value]  FROM VISIT
```

which is more-or-less identical to:

```
SELECT 'WS' AS [Col], WORKSTATION AS [Value] FROM VISIT
UNION
SELECT 'CA' AS [Col], CATEGORY AS [Value]  FROM VISIT
UNION
SELECT 'BU' AS [Col], BUTTON AS [Value]  FROM VISIT
```

This is then one round-trip, etc. I'd probably use an integer (maybe even `tinyint`) for the first column (with the client expected to know that 1 maps to WORKSTATION etc) rather than a varchar, but the above is given for flavor only.

---

Edit re comments; the following takes into account:

- including different data types in the union (converting to a common type)
- using ordinal sorts on the *original* data, so integers are still sorted 1,2,10 (integer sort), not 1,10,2 (string-sort)

TSQL:

```
DECLARE @VISIT TABLE (WORKSTATION int, CATEGORY varchar(10), BUTTON int)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (1,'1',1)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (1,'2',3)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (2,'1',2)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (10,'1',1)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (10,'3',1)
INSERT @VISIT VALUES (10,'1',2)

SELECT x.Col, x.Value
FROM (
  SELECT CAST(1 as tinyint) AS [Col], ROW_NUMBER() over(order by WORKSTATION)
    AS [Sort], CONVERT(varchar(20), WORKSTATION) AS [Value] FROM @VISIT
  UNION
  SELECT CAST(2 as tinyint) AS [Col], ROW_NUMBER() over(order by CATEGORY)
    AS [Sort], CATEGORY AS [Value] FROM @VISIT
  UNION
  SELECT CAST(3 as tinyint) AS [Col], ROW_NUMBER() over (order by BUTTON)
    AS [Sort], CONVERT(varchar(20), BUTTON) AS [Value] FROM @VISIT
) x ORDER BY x.Col, x.Sort
```

Comment: looks great.. when I run i got the conversion error from varchar to tinyint. Which part is tinyint??

Comment: @william - meaning; in real code I would probably have `CAST(1 as tinyint) AS [Col]`, `CAST(2 as tinyint) AS [Col]`, `CAST(3 as tinyint) AS [Col]` instead of `'WS'` etc

Comment: i dun think that the question.. i might b stupid, wht i asked is.. the types of the columns are varchar and the error said error occurred when converting to smallint..

Comment: @william the code I posted in the answer doesn't touch `smallint`; if you are seeing something unexpected you're going to have to help by showing the code that is causing this.

Comment: @Marc, the query is working fine if the column value is int. But the error pops up that cannot convert to smallint when the value is not int. For my case, workstation is int and button is button1, button2 and so on.. So the error pops up that can't convert to int. :(  How am i supposed to cast it to varchar? or is there any other way round?

Comment: @william - I wasn't treating the `WORKSTATION` column as `tinyint` - I was treating my *marker* column (`[Col]`).

Comment: @william the query returns two columns; a marker-column which in the *example* has the literal values `'WS'`, `'CA'`, `'BU'` (meaning: maps to `[WORKSTATION]`, `[CATEGORY]`, `[BUTTON]`. I was merely suggeting that this **marker** could by `tinyint`. Nothing to do with the second col...

Comment: @Marc- Yes, I know but.. as I said I can't retrieve the varchar values. Any way to do that? tkz so much btw..

Comment: @william I don't understand the question... is this simply because in your *actual* system the 3 data columns are a mixture of different types? If so you will need to cast/convert to the most appropriate common-denominator. Otherwise you're going to have to help me out by adding some context.

Comment: @Marc- Sorry. I already solved it. I didn't understand the "Union".
My first statement returns int for Value column.
My second statement returns varchar for Value column.
When i union them, the varchar value can't cast into int.
that's why there is an error.
So I cast int to varchar and the business is done.
But I still can't use "Union All". I can only use "Union". What's the difference? Tkz.

Comment: @william; try `CONVERT(varchar(20), TheFirstColumn)` . The difference is probably blind luck of ordering - it has to infer a column type, so if it sees the int first *boom*. If it sees the varchar first it works. Use the `CONVERT` so that it always sees varchar, then it can't get it wrong

Comment: @Marc- Yes, I already know that. But a minor obstacle comes out. The statement did order itself but.. when it orders the workstation, it orders like 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,... since they are in varchar format. Any idea?

Comment: wht do u mean.. updating answer??

Comment: @william I mean I've edited the answer to show that; it is too big to fit in a comment!

Comment: @Marc- In your new answer, how to make it distinct?

Comment: @william maybe (on the last line) `GROUP BY x.Col, x.Value ORDER BY x.Col, MIN(x.Sort)` ?

Comment: @william if it is grouped by `x.Col, x.Value` it can't be repeated... unless your values are actually `[n]char` with different white-space? The group is on the very last line, yes?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas...

**Two Full Outer Joins:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.workstation, c.category, b.button
  FROM VISIT w FULL OUTER JOIN VISIT c ON (w.workstation = c.category)
  FULL OUTER JOIN VISIT b ON (w.workstation = b.button OR c.category = b.button)
```

**Subqueries for VISIT may speed things up too:**

```
SELECT w.workstation, c.category, b.button
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT workstation FROM VISIT) w 
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM VISIT) c 
             ON (w.workstation = c.category)
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT button FROM VISIT) b 
             ON (w.workstation = b.button OR c.category = b.button)
```

**Ordered if you wish:**

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(w.workstation, c.category, b.button)
```